# Azure cosmos db stored procedure, getting invalid partition key error

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am getting invalid partition key error for below piece of code

```js
const {body: result} = await container.scripts.storedProcedure("bulkUpdate").execute(updateData, {partitionKey: updateData[0].upc});
```

Data is updateData is like below

```
[
   {
      "upc":"351672408367",
      "ndc":"51672408306",
      "description":"HYDROCORTISONE BUTYRATE 0.1% ONT 45 GM",
      "pack_size":"45",
      "unitMeasure":"EA"
   }
]
```

While defining the partition while creating the container i have defined has /upc

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have your parameters reversed. Based on the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/storedprocedure?view=azure-node-latest#execute-any--any----requestoptions-), first parameter to execute method is the partition key and the next one is the input parameters to the procedure.

Please try something like the following (untested code):

```
const {body: result} = await container.scripts.storedProcedure("bulkUpdate").execute(updateData[0].upc, [updateData]);
```

Comment: I followed the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs. You are right about the order